# Which Nonorientable 3 manifolds have torsion in $H_{1}$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

In thinking about closed, nonorientable 3 manifolds I've been interested in finding nonorientable loops which represent torsion classes in homology. More precisely, for a closed nonorientable 3 manifold $M$ I've wondered when one can find a class $\gamma \in H_{1}(M; \mathbb{Z})$ so that $\gamma$ is torsion, and $w_{1}(M)[\bar{\gamma}]$ is nontrivial (where $w_{1}(M)$ is the first Stiefel-Whitney class of the tangent bundle and $\bar{\gamma}$ is the reduction mod 2 of $\gamma$).

This has led me to the following questions:

> > Can one characterize which nonorientable 3 manifolds $M$ have torsion classes in $H_{1}(M ; \mathbb{Z})$?

My list of examples of nonorientable 3 manifolds is short, but among them I've noticed that some do:

1) $S^{1} \times N_{h}$,  where $N_{h} \cong (\mathbb{R}P^{2})^{\#h}$

and some don't:

2) $S^{1} \tilde{\times} S^{2}$

Secondly,

> > For those 3 manifolds $M$ with torsion in $H_{1}(M; \mathbb{Z})$, can one characterize which have torsion classes $\gamma$ satisfying $w_{1}(M)[\bar \gamma]$ =1?

I've noted here as well that some do:

$S^{1} \times N_{1}$

and some don't:

$S^{1} \times N_{2}$.

Comment: I don't know the answer but I'm guessing that if such $\gamma$ exists in $M$, then it also exists in $M \# M'$, which gives more examples.

Comment: I am skeptical there is any characterization.

Comment: @HewWolff, I agree; I think this should follow from additivity of $w_{1}$ under connect sums, but haven't yet written this down.

Comment: @MikeMiller I'm similarly skeptical, but don't really have much evidence for skepticism or optimism. Do you have more classes of examples in mind or some justification for this intuition? My feeling is that the second condition is more likely 'characterizable'.